# How to output multiple curl result with new line but without printing the trailing newline character for each specific request

Tags: bash, rest, api, loops, curl

Please help me with one thing. I'm trying to output in the console the response of curl request in real time for different URL on BASH. But the problem is that I want to output the response for each request without printing a new line in a loop - I want to do it in one string for each request. 
It should be like "echo -n" but for multiple strings.
 And I'm stuck with this

```
SERVER_LIST=("192.168.100.2" "192.168.100.3")

    getMemSize()
    {
        readonly time=$(date -d "1 minutes" +'%H:%M:%S')
        for ip in ${!SERVER_LIST[*]}
        do
          until [ $(curl -sS http://${SERVER_LIST[$ip]}:8080/api/size | jq -r .memory_size) -eq "0" ] || [ $(date +%H:%M:%S) == "$time" ]
          do
            echo -e -n "${SERVER_LIST[$ip]}:" "$(curl -sS http://${SERVER_LIST[$ip]}:8080/api/size| jq -r .memory_size)\\r"
            sleep 1
          done
        done
    }
```

The result will contain only first server in one line:

```
192.168.100.2: 200
```

and every second the value **200** will be decreased until **0**.

But I want to see the result for each CURL response without printing a new line simultaneously. (I mean if I have 2 servers I want to see only **two** lines where the only digit (memory_size) will be changed every second)

The result should update every second like "monitoring page"

```
192.168.100.2: 200
192.168.100.3: 150
```